# How to write the content of a dictionary to a text file?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary object of type Dictionary

and trying to use StreamWriter to output the entire content to a text file but failed to find the correct method from the Dictionary class.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("myfile.txt"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(dictionary.First());

        }
```

I can only retrieve the first element and it is bounded by a square bracket plus a comma separator in between as well:

[Peter, Admin]

and would be nice to have [Peter Admin] (without the comma)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to loop over the entries yourself:

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("myfile.txt"))
    foreach (var entry in dictionary)
        file.WriteLine("[{0} {1}]", entry.Key, entry.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks, my colleague has pointed out I can do something like...

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dictionary)
                    sw.WriteLine(entry.Key + entry.Value);

Answer (score 47):

```
File.WriteAllLines("myfile.txt",
    dictionary.Select(x => "[" + x.Key + " " + x.Value + "]").ToArray());
```

(And if you're using .NET4 then you can omit the final `ToArray` call.)

Comment: I'd also suggest making it an extension method.

Comment: csv style:
   File.WriteAllLines("myfile.txt", dictionary.Select(s => String.Format("{0};{1}", s.Key, s.Value)));

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string>  kvp in dictionary)
{
     System.IO.File.AppendAllText("dictionary.txt", string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", kvp.Key,    kvp.Value, Environment.NewLine));
}
```

Comment: +1 because I'm rewriting methods that take Lists to take Dictionaries instead and I really want to keep using the static `File` class methods. But then I realized that this opens and closes the file every iteration, which is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

```
// Demonstration
private void WriteDictToFile(Dictionary<string, string> someDict, string path) 
{
    using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(path)
    {
        // You can modify <string, string> notation by placing your types.
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvPair in someDict) 
        {
            fileWriter.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", kvPair.Key, kvPair.Value);
        }
        fileWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

And to use in Main

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dataDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
    string n = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter your surname: ");
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    dataDict.Add("Name", n)
    dataDict.Add("Surname", s)
    WriteDictToFile(dataDict, "PATH\\TO\\FILE");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the strings you wish to write, and iterate over the resulting enumeration to write each line:

```
var dataToWrite = from kvp in dictionary
                  select String.Format("[{0} {1}"], kvp.Key kvp.Value);

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("myfile.txt"))
{
    foreach (string dataLine in dataToWrite)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(dataLine);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
File.WriteAllLines("myfile.txt",dictionary.Select(s=>s.ToString());
```

should do it  as the ToString function for dictionary element is defined to put each element in the following format in the text file.

```
[key1,Value1]
[key2,Value2]
.
.
```

Comment: The above makes it easier to open the file later in excel and you will have the key and value seperated if you use "myfile.csv" instead of "myfile.txt"

Answer (score 1):

```
var pairs = from p in yourDictionary.Keys
    select new {Key=p, Value=yourDictionary[p]};

foreach(var pair in pairs)
    yourStreamWriter.WriteLine("Key={0}, Value={1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
```